# is it possible to run a stored procedure from within phpmyadmin 3.4.10.1?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

i m wondering if phpMyAdmin can 'run' a stored procedure. I know I can create stored procedure using the sql tab in phpmyadmin, and that the stored procedure gets stored in the Routines table under InformationSchema database.

When i try to CALL the procedure from within the sql tab of some table inside my database, i get the `#1312 - PROCEDURE dbname.procname can't return a result set in the given context.` error message.

is there some way to call (execute the procedure) from within phpmyadmin? If yes, please let me know where i should enter the sql code for running the proc.

version details:

```
phpmyadmin: 3.4.10.1
php: 5.3.6
mysql: 5.1.63
```

Answer (score 3):

Calling stored procedures directly from phpMyAdmin requires **version 3.5.2.2 of phpMyAdmin** or later.